# Regular Expression to replace integers with floats

Tags: java, regex, actionscript-3

We're trying to replace integer values with float values in a String, for example:

```
#var1 * #var2/ 1+100 - 2 + 1.5 - .5
```

The regular expression should match `1`, `100` and `2`, but not numbers which are already floats, eg `1.5` and `.5`

I've gotten as far as `/[^\w](\d+)/`, which finds digits by themselves.
Now, how do I exclude numbers from this regular expression, that are followed by `\.?\d+`?

The RegEx should work in Java or Actionscript 3.

[Regular Expression Test](http://rubular.com/r/KRbeShId3W)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Using `(?<![.\w])(\d+)(?![.\w])` now, which is @Marko Topolnik's answer with an added capturing group for the digits to be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work in Java: `/(?<![.\w])\d+(?![.\w])/`. It uses both lookahead and lookbehind to stop matching digits that are either preceeded or succeeded by a dot/letter.

Answer (score 1):

Why no trying lookahead? I believe it works with Java, no clue about ActionScript.

`[^\w](\d+)(?![.]\d+)/`

Would match only those sequences of digits not immediately followed by a dot integer(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a n[egative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this

```
(?<!\.\d+)
```

would exclude this, but you need to combine this with an anchor otherwise you will get a parital match.

```
/(?<!\B|\.)(\d+)(?!\.\d+)\b/
```

You should also change the non-word character before the digits. I used here a negative lookbehind assertion `(?<!\B|\.)`. it ensures that there is no dot before the digit or not a non word boundary (double negation to match on a word boundary.)

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30n8f)

Answer (score 0):

If your regex syntax supports lookahead, you can use that.  Java does; not sure about AS3.

```
/[^\w.]\d+(?!\.)/
```

Note that in this case you'd want to use the entire matched string in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is

```
\b(?<!\.)\d+(?!\.)\b
```